# How do I append a shapefile to PostGIS table with multiple geometry fields using ogr2ogr?

Tags: postgis, shapefile, ogr2ogr, append

I am having an issue when trying to append shapefile data to an existing table in my PostGIS database using ogr2ogr. The existing table has multiple geometry fields. When I append the shapefile the attribute data uploads fine but the geometry fields are all NULL. I have tested out the upload appending to a new table with only one geometry field and it works fine, but when there are multiple fields it just fails to input any geometry information.

My command looks something like:

```
ogr2ogr.exe -update -append \
  -f PostgreSQL "PG:host=xxxx port=5432 dbname=yyyy password=***** user=zzz" "C:\xxx.shp" \
  -nlt PROMOTE_TO_MULTI \
  -lco GEOMETRY_NAME=geom \
  -nln schema.tablename \
  -a_srs EPSG:3857
```

How do I make sure my geometry information is also appended?

I have tried using the sql argument to select columns and rename the geometry column to match the one I want the data in, but nothing has worked so far. Any layer creation options are ignored as it is an append.

Answer (score 0):

This may help others even if I it useless for this specific topic.

[ogr2ogr cannot import into table with two geography columns](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/401483/ogr2ogr-cannot-import-into-table-with-two-geography-columns)