# Import a shapefile in a PostGIS table with a custom geometric column name

Tags: postgis, shapefile, geometry, import

PostgreSQL 13.6, PostGIS 3.2, QGIS 3.22

I have a table with several geometric columns:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS activite.prescription
(
gid integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('activite.prescription_gid_seq'::regclass),
...,
geom_l93 geometry(MultiPolygon,2154),
geom_wgs84 geometry(MultiPolygon,4326),
geom_ant geometry(MultiPolygon,32620),
geom_spm geometry(MultiPolygon,32621),
geom_guy geometry(MultiPolygon,32622),
geom_may geometry(MultiPolygon,32738),
geom_reu geometry(MultiPolygon,32740),
geom_pol geometry(MultiPolygon,32706)
)
```

We have to **add** features from shapefiles to this table using QGIS and the plugin `Export to PostgreSQL (connexions available)`.

- Even if I specifiy the name of the geometric column as `GEOMETRY_NAME=geom_l93`, the geom from the shapefile is not imported : the geometry in PostGIS is **empty**.

  > ogr2ogr.exe -progress --config PG_USE_COPY YES --config SHAPE_ENCODING UTF-8 -f PostgreSQL "PG:dbname=xxx host=xxxx port=xxxx user=xxx password=xxx sslmode=disable active_schema=activite" -lco DIM=3 C:/myshp myshp -lco SPATIAL_INDEX=OFF -append -nlt MULTIPOLYGON -lco GEOMETRY_NAME=geom_l93 -nln activite.prescription
- The only way I found is to write the query like this in the previous command:

  > ogr2ogr.exe...PG:...-dialect SQLite -sql "select xxx as yyy,..., geometry as geom_l93 from myshp"

There it works, I can see the features in QGIS.

- But, as many colleagues with varying skills have to import shapefiles, do you know an easier way to do that without writing SQL?

Comment: related: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/401483/ogr2ogr-cannot-import-into-table-with-two-geography-columns

Comment: -lco will only be used when the table is created "Layer Creation Options". Can you have one SRID as the base and then use database triggers to populate the rest? Or even a view on the table for the other SRIDS.

Comment: @HeikkiVesanto : nope because colleagues around the world work datas in their own (local) CRS.